# How to compare one row with all other rows in spark using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

I have 100K+ names in a column. I need to compare each of them to identify if they are same (D'souza, D'souza) or almost same (D'souza, Dsouza).

I tried reading the cassandra table into RDD and did cartesian product of column with itself to form a tuple. But since the column size is 100K this results in huge RDD and eventually the spark job is hanging.

Below is the code that I have :

```
    val valueRdd = sc.cassandraTable("keyspace", "some_table")
    val dataRDD = valueRdd
    .map(row => {
      (
        row
          .getStringOption("name")
          .get,

    }).cache()

    val cartesianResult = dataRDD cartesian dataRDD
    //Followed by some compare logic. May be soundex or some other library or some fuzzy logic.
```

The problem here is that the cartesian result will be order of 100K * 100K which is not ideal. Is there any better way to do this?

The problem statement is to identify the sibling in the given dataset. The dataset will have 100K + data in it.

Comment: What is it that you would like to do with the duplicate/similar names? Deduplicate? Infer data? Or do you literally just need every possible pair of names and whether or not they are same/similar?

Comment: Idea is to identify siblings. In this case, names can have small variations but in the end the refer to the same person. Eg: D'souza, Dsouza is the same person though the name differ by " ' ". So I am after identifying all such variations and replacing all siblings with a common name. Eg : All instances of D'souza, Dsouza or D souza or similar names will have common name called Dsouza.

Answer (score 5):

The list is small enough you could convert the list into a broadcast variable and have each node compare it's part of the rdd to the broadcasted list:

```
val valueRddBC =sc.broadcast(valueRdd.collect())
val similarPairsRdd = valueRdd.flatMap(x => 
    valueRddBc.value.filter(y => dist(x,y) > threshold)
                  .map(y => (x,y)))
```

100k is small enough though that you could do the whole thing in the driver if you wanted to (if the dist function is not expensive this would likely be faster).

If the RDD is really large, you can map items to some kind of fingerprint to ignore most of the irrelevant items with a strategy such as a LSH (locally sensitive hashing).  This is an approximate nearest neighbors algorithm that gives O(1) for finding the closest item.

Answer (score 0):

Does your comparison function do anything more complex to compare names?  If all you're doing is removing spaces and apostrophes, you could simply convert the RDD into a pair RDD keyed on the simplified version of the name, and then use groupBy to group the similar names.  e.g.:

```
scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize( List("d'souza", "d souza", "Dsouza") )
scala> rdd.map{ 
     |     case x => x.replaceAll(" ", "").replaceAll("'","").toLowerCase -> x
     | }.groupByKey.collect
res3: Array[(String, Iterable[String])] = Array((dsouza,CompactBuffer(d'souza, d souza, Dsouza)))
```