# How to compare a row with all other rows in spark dataset?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I have a spark dataset which was loaded from MySQL, i want to compare each row with all other rows in the dataset and create a new dataset using the results obtained. is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: You can look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41252719/how-to-compare-one-row-with-all-other-rows-in-spark-using-scala. Else what kind of comparison do you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to join two datasets by matching fields of rows.
You can match two datasets like that and join both

val Result = DF1.join(DF2, (DF1("USER_ID") === DF2("USER_ID")) &&(DF1("SESSION_ID") === DF2("SESSION_ID")) &&(DF1("DATE") === DF2("DATE")) )
.select(DF1("USER_ID"),DF1("SESSION_ID"),DF1("DATE"),DF2("COUNTRY"))